# Check string elements in an array to manipulate

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have the following array returning from a service

```
indexLabelServices = [ ' Pear', ' Apple', ' Banana',' Peach',' Orange',' Cherry' ]
```

For each element of the array i want to give a different `label` ( translation )

This is my code

```
  const convertServicesLabels = (indexLabelServices) => {
    let label="";
    for (let index = 0; index < indexLabelServices.length; ++index) {
      const element = indexLabelServices[index];
      if(element === " Pear){
        label=Pera;
      }else  if(element ===" Apple"){
        label=Mela;
      }else  if(element ===" Banana"){
        label=Platano;
      }else  if(element ===" Peach"){
        label=Pesca
      }else  if(element ===" Orange"){
        label=Arancia;
      }else  if(element ===" Cherry"){
        label=Ciliegia;
      }
    }
    return label;
  }
```

The result i have with this method is that the only the element `Orange` is translated to `Arancia`, not others element get transalated.

What am i doing wrong? How can i manipulate/translate any element of the array `indexLabelServices` ?

Comment: Your function iterates over an array but returns a single value at the end. So, you'd only get the last item translated.

Comment: yes, do you have the answer to get aal the items translated too?

Comment: You can return an array instead of a single value.

Comment: what exactly is the output

Comment: The output is only "Arancia"

Comment: Well you have syntax errors in your code

Comment: another option would be to use a key value pair. easy to extend as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is located within a for loop where you every iteration rewrite variable `label`. Another problem is iterating over that array. When you do `++index` then variable index increment before enter the for loop body so instead try to use `index++`. In this case will be index increment after one iteration of for loop.

If you need to return array of all translation edit your code to something like this:

```js
  let indexLabelServices = [ ' Pear', ' Apple', ' Banana',' Peach',' Orange',' Cherry' ];
  
  const convertServicesLabels = (indexLabelServices) => {
    let translations = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < indexLabelServices.length; index++) {
      const element = indexLabelServices[index];
      if(element === " Pear"){
          translations[index] = 'Pera';
      }
      else if(element ===" Apple"){
          translations[index] = 'Mela';
      }
      else if(element ===" Banana"){
         translations[index] = 'Platano';
      }
      else if(element ===" Peach"){
          translations[index] = 'Pesca';
      }
      else if(element ===" Orange"){
          translations[index] = 'Arancia';
      }
      else if(element ===" Cherry"){
          translations[index] = 'Ciliegia';
      }
    }
    return translations;
  }
  
  console.log(convertServicesLabels(indexLabelServices));
```

Answer (score 2):

you are only returning the last element you are storing in label not mutating the array, try using map over the list.

```js
let indexLabelServices = [' Pear', ' Apple', ' Banana', ' Peach', ' Orange', ' Cherry']

indexLabelServices = indexLabelServices.map(element => {
  switch (element.toLocaleLowerCase().trim()) {
    case "pear":return "Pera";
    case "apple":return "Mela";
    case "banana":return "Platano";
    case "peach":return "Pesca";
    case "orange":return "Arancia";
    case "cherry":return "Ciliegia";
    default:return "Unknown";
  }
})

console.log(indexLabelServices)
```

Comment: For quality reasons can you use switch instead?

Answer (score 1):

Set up an object containing the translations, then map the original array to a new array using the array elements to return the translation from the dictionary.

```js
const indexLabelServices = [' Pear', ' Apple', ' Banana', ' Peach', ' Orange', ' Cherry'];
const dict = {' Pear':'Pera', ' Apple':'Mela', ' Banana':'Platano', ' Peach':'Pesca', ' Orange':'Arancia', ' Cherry':'Ciliegia'};

console.log(dict);
let translations = indexLabelServices.map(x=>dict[x]);
console.log(translations)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use 1 variable `label` to assign the value, so it will only assign the last value.

Also a better option is to use `switch` if you only want to do give value based on expression.

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case.

```js
let indexLabelServices = [' Pear', ' Apple', ' Banana', ' Peach', ' Orange', ' Cherry']
    let result = []
for (let i of indexLabelServices) {
  switch (i) {
      case " Pear":
      result.push("Pera");
      break;
    case " Apple":
       result.push( "Mela");
      break;
    case " Banana":
       result.push("Platano");
      break;
    case " Orange":
       result.push("Arancia");
      break;
     case " Peach":
     result.push("Pesca");
     break
    case " Cherry":
       result.push("Ciliegia");
      break;
  }
}
console.log(result)
```